# How can I avoid passwords

Tags: windows, security

I'm the default IT guy at a small family business. We have 5-10 employees that only work at the office for about half the year. Because of this, it's a pain to have unique passwords - so people seem to just use a common password for all machines. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions of how to make this more secure (without the need to remember passwords).

We use Windows machines. Log in is done locally. We do have Active Directory when accessing a central file server. We could rely on AD if that is something that is advisable.

I've thought maybe some kind of RSA or Yubikey - just have them plug it in to log in and then when they leave for the year they can just give us back the key. However, as the Admin I would need to log in to their machine to install apps (so would I need a master key, or something)?

Would I use AD for my log in and then just "install for all users on this machine"? So maybe this is two questions? Main question would be avoiding passwords for all the employees. But related would be how could I log into their account if I didn't have their key?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you could use some sort of smart card, but those are to be used as a second factor, in conjunction with a password.

Honestly, being able to remember secure credentials are an essential part of modern life. It is perfectly reasonable for you to require them to remember their passwords. If your users have trouble remembering passwords, recommend they use a password database like lastpass or 1password.

If you need to reset passwords periodically, then so be it. Doing so is much easier than dealing with a compromised network.